# how to convert these value to array or obejct

Tags: php

I have some data which I have decode by using base64_decode. After the decode I got values like this:

```
{ 
    "quantity" = "1"; 
    "product-id" = "gigaplex.subscription.monthly"; 
    "item-id" = "421702921"; 
    "version-external-identifier" = "4000187"; 
    "purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
    "app-item-id" = "421702836"; 
    "transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
    "original-purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
    "original-transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
    "bid" = "com.gigaplex.gigaplexHD"; 
    "bvrs" = "1.4"; 
}
```

but my problem is I can't extract the specified value from this string. Please give some suggestion to extract this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to json with a couple of str_replace functions then decode it :

```
<?php

$testval = '{ 
   "quantity" = "1"; 
   "product-id" = "gigaplex.subscription.monthly"; 
   "item-id" = "421702921"; 
   "version-external-identifier" = "4000187"; 
   "purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
   "app-item-id" = "421702836"; 
   "transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
   "original-purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
   "original-transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
   "bid" = "com.gigaplex.gigaplexHD"; 
   "bvrs" = "1.4";}';

$testval = str_replace('";','",',$testval); // replace the colons
$testval = str_replace(' = ',' : ',$testval);  // replace the equals
$testval = substr($testval,0,-2) . '}';  // remove the final comma

var_dump(json_decode($testval));
```

http://codepad.org/kOc862aD

** works but im sure can be improved

Comment: yeah i just noticed that ... was working 2 seconds before i posted it .... gonna remove my answer and rework ! ta

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using regular expressions

```
$data = '{ 
   "quantity" = "1"; 
   "product-id" = "gigaplex.subscription.monthly"; 
   "item-id" = "421702921"; 
   "version-external-identifier" = "4000187"; 
   "purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
   "app-item-id" = "421702836"; 
   "transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
   "original-purchase-date" = "2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT"; 
   "original-transaction-id" = "30000011473303"; 
   "bid" = "com.gigaplex.gigaplexHD"; 
   "bvrs" = "1.4"; 
}';

preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/', $data, $matches );

$data = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
print_r( $data );

/*
Array
(
    [quantity] => 1
    [product-id] => gigaplex.subscription.monthly
    [item-id] => 421702921
    [version-external-identifier] => 4000187
    [purchase-date] => 2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT
    [app-item-id] => 421702836
    [transaction-id] => 30000011473303
    [original-purchase-date] => 2011-08-09 18:38:52 Etc/GMT
    [original-transaction-id] => 30000011473303
    [bid] => com.gigaplex.gigaplexHD
    [bvrs] => 1.4
)
*/
```

Comment: Seems there is a bug in some versions of PHP - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31501  Works on my system

Comment: This one working for me but i don't know why its not working in some-other versions..

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string to an array on the /r/n characters. Then split the string on the " = " tokens and finally trim the resulting string-pairs on the space and " character, leaving only a nice set of key and value pairs!

```
$lines = explode('/r/n', $string);
$results = Array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($key, $value) = preg_split('@" = "@', $line);
    $key = trim($key, ' "');
    $value = trim($value, ' "');
    $results[$key] = $value;
}
```

(untested ;))